# How exactly does the statistics mechanic gather its information?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How exactly does the statistics mechanic gather its information?

- Does it matter if I'm actually 'logged in' or 'playing offline'?
- Does it matter if I'm playing in any one particular world I've created?

My stats seem to be all over the place, and sometimes I know for a FACT their wrong, as annotated in [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47756/im-levelling-up-too-quickly-what-could-be-the-cause) question.

So... what gives?

Comment: Good question.. Ive just always gone 'Well it works about as well as the rest of the game' and ignored em :)

Comment: @James: Normally that would be my take on it as well, except if I can possibly answer this question, I can possibly answer my other question which is linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statistics are stored in your Minecraft data folder under `stats`, and [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Statistics) has some details on the format. We can see from the filenames (e.g. `stats_kpreid_unsent.dat`) that they are stored per-user. It *does* matter whether you are playing offline, because if you are offline it is as if you are playing the default username “`Player`” and so those statistics will be kept separately.

The statistics are collected across all worlds.

I agree that the statistics are screwy in some cases, but I don't have any specific info. Besides various obvious general flaws (e.g. counting all dyes as Ink Sacs), Minecraft thinks I've crafted more sugar than torches...

Comment: when you say collected across all worlds, do you mean, for example: that my mob kills statistic is the total mobs from every world? not just the mobs that particular character in that particular world has killed?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Actions in creative mode also count.