# What is Best way to earn XP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

my friends and I were playing on a world together, but now, we ask ourselves: what is the best way to earn xp?

It was a mob tower, but they never decide to fall. And for mobspawners, we have tried but the yield is poor !!!

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too vague to get a decent answer on this site and might be closed unless you edit it. Perhaps a better question might be: 'Why don't the mobs fall out of my mob grinder?'.

Comment: "Best" is subjective. Blaze farms have a very high EXP yield but on the other hand are rather expensive and very dangerous to build.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/39458/38952

Comment: The answer is currently mining nether quartz is the best way to gain Xp. That is an answer on the linked question, all be it it only has my up vote currently.

Answer (score 3):

EXP only drops when a player kills the mob, so a mob tower won't work for your plan. Also, mobs won't walk over edges on their own. You need to push them with a water current or piston. Although the yield is "poor" in a mob spawner system where you kill manually, that's really your only option on Vanilla Minecraft.

You gain small amounts of exp for mining. a Good mining expedition will easily net you 15+ levels. Killing passive mobs (cows/sheep/pigs) also give a small handful of exp. You could use this and make a breeder slaughterhouse.

But as I already stated, a set up Mob Spawner will be your optimal exp flow.

Comment: What is best in a mob grinder is to drop them 22 blocks, so that it almost kills them, but not quite. They then only take one punch to kill, so it's the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [this enderman farm by Panda](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMbn3-_6so0) or [this blaze farm by Etho](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrtcJ4c_6oQ). By far those two are one of the best XP sources in the vanilla game.