# How can I make an automatic wheat/potato/carrot/beetroot farm?

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-legacy-console

So obviouslly I don't know afk farms, or how to even start one. So I came to my trusty friends. I am getting tired of breaking about 500 stocks of weat every 1 hour. So it's time for a change!

How can I make a farm that plants seeds, and breaks them for me?

Should I use villagers? If so how could I set that up, without making the villager taking my precious golden grain?

Also how do you get villagers to farm carrots?

P.S. Im playing on PS3, with 1.16.
Thanks for your time!
Sincerly, Goals.

Comment: I've fixed it for you, but note for the future that PS3 is legacy console edition, not bedrock edition

Comment: The only way you can do afk farms is with villagers, you can break stuff with redstone but can´t plant them. Search on youtube, you´ll find a complete tutorial for that easily.

Comment: That's why I came here. YouTube is blocked for me. Also thanks Penguin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allegedly Legacy Console is *almost* identical to Java - but there are some differences, so I can't guarantee this will work; I have experience with JE and no way to test it on Legacy Console, so I'd advise first to try everything in creative, before you commit to building it in your survival world.

In 1.16 villager based beetroot, carrot and potato farms are still doable, though a bit of a chore. Wheat unfortunately becomes a bread farm. Your best bet is to use an automatic bonemeal farm, and an afk nanofarm for crops.

For bonemeal, there are dozens of various designs varying in complexity and efficiency; probably the best approach for an only moderately technically inclined player is a general mob farm, and crafting skeleton bones into bonemeal. I can recommend [Gnembon's simple mob farm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guvMmdeZqiI) (with [1.15-1.16 errata](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63Q8Thtt7wY) ) as a good, high-efficiency design. The simple mod grinder "in the sky" described [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/377339/9440) will work less efficiently but should be easier to build - and with killing floor a couple blocks lower, can act fully automatically, without player interaction. Still, if you want an overview of better bonemeal options, that's a subject for a different question.

Once you have your bonemeal supply secured, there's a number of nanofarm designs that work. [Ilmango's design for 1.14+](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjblZygQH88) is probably the best currently available:

Start with 5 dispensers facing into a single space.

[image]

Add powered rails on all the dispensers. An observer watching one of the rails, another looking upwards from the central dispenser, 2 powered rails on top of them.

[image]

A lever under the dispenser with observer above; flick it to switch the incessant clicking off.

[image]

In a corner away from the lever place an observer looking up, a powered rail on top. A full solid opaque block below it, and a piston under a side dispenser, facing outwards. This is the critical part of the mechanism responsible for breaking crops - extended piston lets light in, retracted cuts it off and makes grown crops pop off.

[image]

Opposite from the piston, using temporary blocks, place a stair block facing the center and waterlog it. Under the central space, place a dirt block, then hoe it into farmland.

[image]

Add opaque full blocks everywhere around the farmland (including below); add an observer looking at the lever right from it.

[image]

Add a block behind the observer, and two sticky pistons adjacent to it; two blocks on these pistons will form a "door" that closes after the player enclosing the space inside in complete darkness when the side-piston is retracted, making any crops pop off. Add some blocks for entrance, and a slab in front of the block below the farmland.

[image]

Light-proof the room with two extra blocks on the sides of the slab

[image]

Afterwards, fill all dispensers completely with bonemeal, grab a stack of seeds or crops to be grown, crawl into the space on the slab (sneak), flick the lever, and aim at the right dispenser through the crack between the dispenser above you, and farmland. Shift-rightclick the seeds to plant them and hold the rightclick. If they pop off without growing, release RMB and retry - there's about 50% chance of getting the moment right and have the farm produce crops. This will continue until all bonemeal is depleted, producing good several stacks of crops per run.

[image]